# Override created_at value

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to insert date into created at  but nothing worked

I tried to use create as normal

```
$this->create([ 'product_id' => "$id", 'shop_name' => $shop,'created_at' => $date ]);
```

I tried to change the date format to match laravel

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($id['created_at']));
```

I also tried to user mutators to change the value each time

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['created_at'] = $value;
}
```

How can I set a specific date in `created_at`  rather than the default date?

Comment: Well, your attribute in the mutator is created not created_at, but setting the value of created_at when creating should work.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Devon I changed to created_at, anyway it didn't solve it,   the value is not  being overridden  and the stored date is  '2018-02-06' for all records.   I really don't know why!

Comment: First you need to take a step back and think if changing the created_at date is reasonable. Normally you'd never need to change that date.

Comment: @apokryfos   I'm using API  and I must change it to match the other database  otherwise  I won't attempt to change it

Comment: In that case you should have defined your table with date fields like `API_created_date` and `API_updated_date` to indicate what they actually hold. More intuitive and no problems updating. If you're not too deep in the project now I suggest you change that

Comment: If  there's no way to override it  I will follow your suggestion. I never through  it will be so hard  like this.

Comment: @JoumanaIssa are these values fillable in your model?   What is the value of the $guarded or $fillable properties?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have fillable or guarded arrays set for your model?

If so, the `create` method will skip the fields that are not mass assignable.

If you want to fill in your own, you can do something like this:

```
$product = app(Product::class);
$product->timestamps = false; // disable timestamps for this creation

// set what you want to set
$product->product_id = $id;
$product->shop_name = $shop;
$product->created_at = $datetime; // <- datetime here
$product->save();
```

Although, if you look at the code (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php`), and the created_at field is fillable, it should not set another value if it was set during creation. (See the `isDirty` check there)

---

If you never wish to use the created_at and updated_at the normal way, just set timestamps to false in your model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Comment: I've used Laravel v5.5. I don't have to use `$product->timestamps = false;`. Moreover, I've just used this: `$product->setCreatedAt($datetime);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set your timestamp in your Model to false

```
timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, but I thought I'd add that you can also use the `Model::unguard()` method to temporarily disable mass assignment on the model, which will also let you set custom values for `created_at` on the fly, as well as anything else protected by MA. Note that it also cascades to child relationships, as per below:

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    User::unguard();

    $user->drill_completions()->create([
        'day' => null,
        'sequence_completed_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->subHours(32) // unguard has been set on the parent model, but here we are using it to enable setting created_at on the child relationship
    ]);

    User::reguard();
```

As above, you can reset again using `Model::reguard();`.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, it's helpful to step through the Laravel framework code itself.

If you look at `Builder::create()`, you can see it's just a convenience method for creating a new model instance and then saving it.

This ends up calling `Model::performInsert()`, which calls the HasTimestamps trait's `updateTimestamps()` method before performing the insert.

In `HasTimestamps::updateTimestamps()` you'll see that it only sets `created_at` if the attribute is not "dirty".  It will be dirty because you've set it explicitly (See `HasAttributes::isDirty()`).

So long story short, the behavior should be that if you specify `created_at` specifically, your value overrides the default value.  If it's not, it's likely because you have the model's $guarded or $fillable property set in a way that excludes the timestamps.